# On a web form, how can I move a value from an 'unselected' to a 'selected' group using javascript console?

Tags: html, forms

I'm trying to semi-automate form filling, but can't use Selenium or any other tool that requires installation. The forms have various ways of adding text, including text boxes, drop downs, radio buttons, and two boxes in parallel with a list of items, which you can move the items between so they're either selected or not selected. I don't even know the correct term for this but to describe it: the pages loads with 'red' and 'green' and 'blue' in the unselected list, and you can click to move over whichever colours you want into the selected list before submitting the form.

For text boxes, I've been using this to good effect:

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value = hello;
```

I've tried experimenting with the selected/unselected list so that I can input some code into the console and it auto-moves the right colours to the selected list. I can get the colour highlighted in the unselected list, but can't seem to get in over to the selected list. There is a mouse click involved, which I suspect may be my undoing. Is there a way to move the colours over into the selected list using input into the console? Below is the HTML for the selected/unselected lists.

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <label for="colour_type">Colour type:</label>  <div class="content">
  
  <div>
  <div style="float: left">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0.5em">Unassociated</div>
    <select name="unassociated_colour_type[]" id="unassociated_colour_type" multiple="multiple" class="sf_admin_multiple" size="10">
<option value="1">red</option>
<option value="5">green</option>
<option value="7">blue</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left">
    <input type="image" name="commit" src="/admin/sf/sf_admin/images/next.png" style="border: 0" onclick="double_list_move($('unassociated_colour_type'), $('associated_colour_type')); return false;" /><br />
    <input type="image" name="commit" src="/admin/sf/sf_admin/images/previous.png" style="border: 0" onclick="double_list_move($('associated_colour_type'), $('unassociated_colour_type')); return false;" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: left">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0.5em">Associated</div>
    <select name="associated_colour_type[]" id="associated_colour_type" multiple="multiple" class="sf_admin_multiple-selected" size="10"></select>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: both" />
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please also supply the javascript in the target web. I cannot make a working example from just html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after in moving the option from one box to the other, you can do this with the following.

```
// grab the two elements
unAss = document.getElementById("unassociated_colour_type");
ass   = document.getElementById("associated_colour_type");

// move element 3 to the second box
ass.add(unAss[2]);
```

NB this can be reversed with unAss.add(ass[n]) where n is the poision in the list starting from zero.

Take care moving items as the list reference will change therefore when itterating through you may find it better to count backwards.

Comment: Thanks automate, worked perfectly. I have another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080396/insert-text-into-tinymce-from-console) related to the above if you wanted to take a look.