# Insert text into TinyMCE from console

Tags: forms, console

This question is a follow on from the question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055632/on-a-web-form-how-can-i-move-a-value-from-an-unselected-to-a-selected-group).

I'm trying to semi-auto complete a web form through the console. I can't use Selenium or any other tool that needs to be installed. I want to be able to paste the entire length of code into the console and for it to auto-complete everything when I press enter.

I think I've got most of it sorted. One of the last puzzles I've got to solve is how to get text entered into a TinyMCE text box. I believe the ID for the text area is 'colour_summary'. For other text boxes I've been successful using:

```
document.getElementById('textbox').value = hello;
```

But the same approach doesn't work with the TinyMCE text box. I'm not even sure I'm including the right part of the webpage, but below is my best guess. Grateful for any suggestions.

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "exact",
  language: "en",
  elements: "colour_summary",
  plugins: "table,advimage,advlink,flash",
  theme: "advanced",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
  theme_advanced_path_location: "bottom",
  theme_advanced_buttons1: "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,sub,sup,separator,charmap",
  theme_advanced_buttons2: "bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,image,flash,separator,cleanup,removeformat,separator,code",
  theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols",
  extended_valid_elements: "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|style]",
  relative_urls: false,
  debug: false
  
  ,width:550,height:350,cleanup_on_startup:true,theme:"advanced",theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",theme_advanced_toolbar_align:"left",theme_advanced_path_location:"bottom",theme_advanced_blockformats:"h3,h4,h5",theme_advanced_buttons1:"cut,copy,paste,pasteword,pastetext,separator,undo,redo,separator,bold,italic,underline,separator,sub,sup,separator,charmap,removeformat,code,separator,link,unlink,image,hr",theme_advanced_buttons2:"fontsizeselect,styleselect,forecolor,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,spellchecker",plugins:"paste,table,advlink,advimage,spellchecker",paste_create_paragraphs:true,paste_create_linebreaks:true,paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,paste_convert_middot_lists:true,paste_convert_headers_to_string:true,file_browser_callback : "ajaxfilemanager",relative_urls:true,content_css:"/css/frontend/select_styles.css",apply_source_formatting:true
});
//]]>
</script><textarea name="colour[summary]" id="colour_summary" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea>    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample document that will write html formated text to an tinyMCE box on a web page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>
<body onload="writeToTinyMCE()">

  <textarea name="colour[summary]" id="colour_summary" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea>      

<script>
function writeToTinyMCE() {
  doc=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
  doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;  
  doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = "<p>Sample <b>Bold</b> <i>italic</i></p><p>New Para</p>";
}
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @automate but how do I use the above, and where would my text go? Pasting it into the console returns a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. And can this be pasted in at the same time as my other commands like getelementbyid?

Comment: You can just paste    
    doc = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
    doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML;  
    doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = "<p>Sample <b>Bold</b> <i>italic</i></p><p>New Para</p>";    
in the console for it to populate the text area. Be sure this is the only iframe in your doc else doc=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]; will need to have 0 updated to be the relevant iframe number. Put whatever you want in place of the "<p>Sample <b>Bold</b> <i>italic</i></p><p>New Para</p>"

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was iframe 1 I needed. I also need to be able to set the font to Verdana 7.5 or to simply insert the text as plain text depending on the situation. For Verdana, I tried putting this into the console but it didn't work: `doc = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1]; doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML; doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = <font face="Verdana" size="7.5px">"Input text."</font>`.  I guess I'm pretty wide of the mark...

Comment: Try doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-size:7.5px;font-family:verdana\">Input Text</span>"; for 7.5px Verdana OR "doc.contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML = "Input Text" as the last line for plain text

Comment: Great, making some progress now. Still working on this project, various difficulties have popped up but making headway on most of them. Will likely ask one or two more questions in separate posts.